# Adding HTML via JS to a specific child-Element

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I have a very specific situation where I have ~50 child-divs which I cannot influence directly, that is, I cannot add classes or ids to one specific child-div nor alter the div via HTML because they are created automatically.
They appear in a simple grid/flexbox, two boxes next to each other. I already altered some of them with nth-child, but now I want to add individual headlines between f.ex. div 30 and 31.

Up until now, when I wanted some of the fields to be bigger, I addressed one of the child-divs directly via nth-child.

Here's the basic structure:

```
    <div class="parent">
      {$content} // basically <div>{$single-box-content}</div>
   </div>
```

And the CSS I currently use:

```
 .parent {
    width: 800px;
    display: flex;
    gap: 20px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    
    .parent:nth-child(10) {
    width:800px;
    }
```

That worked quite well. However, now that I want to have a headline *above* one of the divs (not inside), it doesn't work. When I try this:

```
.parent:nth-child(31):before {
content: "Headline";
display: block;
}
```

It appears inside the child-div, not above it. I cannot add a div to the HTML part, since all of them are created automatically in the backend (it's a form).

I wondered if it is possible to use JavaScript with some element.innerHTML, but I am at the very beginning of learning JS and I couldn't find anything (I could adapt) to address specific child-Elements in JS.
Is there a frontend solution to my problem?

Comment: _"to address specific child-Elements in JS"_ - go look into `querySelector`/ `querySelectorAll`, they allow you to select elements using the same selectors you would use in CSS directly. Combine with a method such as `insertBefore`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With JS you can add classes, IDs, append HTML-elements to the DOM and so much more.

Below shows you how to both to insert an `h2`, but also how to add a class to an element of your choosing - I used `:nth-child(3)` for illustration purposes, but you can just swap that with `:nth-child(31)`. The code is explained in comments in the snippet.

```js
// finding the child element with nth-child selector
let selected = document.querySelector('.parent:nth-child(3)');

// giving it a class name
selected.classList.add('parentClass');

// creating a h2 element
let header = document.createElement("h2");
// the text inside the h2 element
let headerText = document.createTextNode("headline");

// appending the text to the h2 element
header.append(headerText);

// giving the child a class name
header.classList.add('childClass');

// appending the headline above/before the selected element 
selected.parentNode.insertBefore(header, selected);
```

```css
/* the class applied with JS */

.parentClass {
  background-color: red;
}

.childClass {
background-color: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">parent 1</div>
<div class="parent">parent 2</div>
<div class="parent">parent 3</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the explanation is great! But when I try to use it, the parentClass-class isn't picked up, no red background (or any background at all for that block). The headline is inserted, though. I didn't change anything from your code but the .parent:nth-child(3) to match the original parent-class name. Do you have any idea why? Do you want me to share the code? (It's nothing but a combination of yours and mine, though.)

Comment: Try pasting your code into a codepen/jsfiddle and link it in a comment on this answer, I can take a look at it @Kreuzkoenig

Comment: Thanks for your help and sorry for the delay! I could only setup a very simplified mock because I'm working with a board software (MyBB) and the templates there are fragmented. Unfortunately, the mockup works concerning the class, but that means I have to search for the issue in my templates, that's a great help. However, the main problem I have can be seen there: the headline appears but the box beneath it gets the white background. However, I would need to have the headline as a separate box with a separate class that I can manipulate. https://codepen.io/kreuzkoenig/pen/vYdyVLx

Comment: Hey @Kreuzkoenig, that is because the class is given to the `selected`-element. The element that is created and appended to the DOM is the `header`-element. The reason the box beneath it gets the white background is because thats the `selected`-element. I suspect you wanted a container for the `h2` as well, so I modified your pen with some more JS to help you achieve that. Explanation is in comments: https://codepen.io/sigurdmazanti/pen/LYQbqqL

Comment: Thanks, that was it! And the explanation is great :-)